# how to extract digits from column names in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, string, dataframe

I have

```
df.columns
Index(['location', 'date', 
       'deaths_2020_all_ages', 'average_deaths_2015_2019_all_ages',
       'deaths_2015_all_ages', 'deaths_2016_all_ages', 'deaths_2017_all_ages',
       'deaths_2018_all_ages', 'deaths_2019_all_ages', 'deaths_2010_all_ages',
       'deaths_2011_all_ages', 'deaths_2012_all_ages', 'deaths_2013_all_ages',
       'deaths_2014_all_ages', 'Week', 'deaths_2021_all_ages', 'w'],
      dtype='object')
```

I want to rename the deaths columns such as 'deaths_2014_all_ages' to '2014'.

I have tried this

```
cols =[x for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.extract(r'([ab])?(\d)')]]

# KeyError: 2
```

and

```
cols =[x for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.replace('[a-z]+_\d{4}_[a-z]+_[a-z]+', '\d{4}', regex=True)]]

# KeyError: '\\d'
# error: bad escape \d at position 0
```

any advice? thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to rename the columns with only the number, i.e. 'deaths_2018_all_ages' will be 2018?

Comment: yes.   trying to rename as the numbers only.

Comment: what about "'average_deaths_2015_2019_all_ages'"?

Comment: More, what about `avg2005_2015_all_ages`? Also, if `deaths_` must precede the number, you need to include it to the pattern.

Comment: yep, dont need the average ones. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to extract the dates from the columns starting in "death", you could use a regex (here: first number or full string if not starting with "death"):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('(\d+|^(?!death).*$)', expand=False)
```

columns before:

```
Index(['location', 'date', 'deaths_2020_all_ages',
       'average_deaths_2015_2019_all_ages', 'deaths_2015_all_ages',
       'deaths_2016_all_ages', 'deaths_2017_all_ages', 'deaths_2018_all_ages',
       'deaths_2019_all_ages', 'deaths_2010_all_ages', 'deaths_2011_all_ages',
       'deaths_2012_all_ages', 'deaths_2013_all_ages', 'deaths_2014_all_ages',
       'Week', 'deaths_2021_all_ages', 'w'],
      dtype='object')
```

columns after:

```
Index(['location', 'date', '2020', 'average_deaths_2015_2019_all_ages', '2015',
       '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014',
       'Week', '2021', 'w'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x: re.sub('^\D*(\d+).*', r'\1',x))
```

If `deaths_` must appear before the digits, just add it:

```py
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x: re.sub('^\D*deaths_(\d+).*', r'\1',x))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3e7URU/1). The `^\D*(\d+).*` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digit chars
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

The `\1` in the replacement is a backreference to Group 1 value.

Your regex approach can be fixed with

```py
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x: re.sub('^.*?_(\d{4})_.*', r'\1',x))
# or
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x: re.sub('^.*?deaths_(\d{4})_.*', r'\1',x))
```

where

- `^.*?_` - matches the start of string, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible and then a `_`
- `(\d{4})` - Group 1: four digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If all columns that you want to rename have this exact format and you don't want to rename the columns containing averages you could do this (as an option that doesn't require regex):

```
cols = [ c.split("_")[1] if "deaths_" in c else c for c in df.columns ]
```

Which on a smaller examples would look like:

```
>>> df.columns = [ "deaths_123_all", "deaths_456_all", "w" ]
>>> [ c.split("_")[1] if "deaths_" in c else c for c in df.columns ]
[ "123", "456", "w" ]
```